# Client&Server flushing buffer

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server, client

I have written a code for a simple Client/Server. The code does the following when it runs.

First the Server waits for a message from the Client and then asks the user to enter a message to send to Client. When the Client first starts to run it asks the user to enter a message to send to the Server and then waits for a reply from the Server.

The Program works fine when I send the first message from the Client to the Server, it appears and then the server ask me to write a message to send to the Client here the problem begins:

I type the message and press enter the message is sent to the client and then the Server receives the same previous message and prompts me to enter a message for the Client. Messages sent either from the server or the client don't get read and printed immediately unless I type in the Server another message then it shows the previous message sent from the client.

Server Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

static void bail( const char* on_what ){
fputs(strerror(errno),stderr);
fputs(": ",stderr);
fputs(on_what,stderr);
fputc('\n',stderr);
exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int sockfd, bindfd, listenfd, acceptfd, writefd, readfd, len_inet;
struct sockaddr_in address_server, address_client;
char *server_address = "192.168.1.10";
char *server_portno = "9100";
char readBuffer[256], writeBuffer[256];

memset(&address_server, 0, sizeof address_server);
address_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
address_server.sin_port = htons(atoi(server_portno));
address_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_address);
if(address_server.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
    bail("bad address");

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if( sockfd == -1 )
    bail("socket()");
printf("socket created\n");

bindfd = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address_server, sizeof address_server);
if( bindfd == -1 )
    bail("bind()");
printf("bind done\n");

listenfd = listen(sockfd, 10);
if( listenfd == -1 )
    bail("listen()");
printf("Listening to Client\n");

len_inet = sizeof address_client;

acceptfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address_client, &len_inet);
if( acceptfd == -1 )
    bail("accept()");
    printf("Connection accepted\n");

while(1){

    printf("Reading from Client...\n");
    readfd = read(acceptfd, &readBuffer, sizeof readBuffer-1);
    if( readfd == -1 )
        bail("read()");

    printf("Message from Client: %s\n", readBuffer);

    printf("Enter a message to send to Client:\n");
    fgets(writeBuffer, 255, stdin);
    writefd = write(acceptfd, writeBuffer, sizeof writeBuffer);
    if( writefd == -1 )
        bail("write()");
}

close(acceptfd);
printf("Closing Connection\n");

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Client Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void static bail( const char* on_what ){
fputs(strerror(errno),stderr);
    fputs(": ",stderr);
    fputs(on_what,stderr);
    fputc('\n',stderr);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

int sockfd, connectfd, readfd, writefd, len_inet;
struct sockaddr_in address_server;
char *server_address = "192.168.1.240";
char *server_portno = "9100";
char readBuffer[256], writeBuffer[256];

memset(&address_server, 0, sizeof address_server);
address_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
address_server.sin_port = htons(atoi(server_portno));
address_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_address);
if( address_server.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
    bail("bad address");

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if( sockfd == -1 )
    bail("socket()");
printf("socket created\n");

len_inet = sizeof address_server;

connectfd = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address_server, len_inet);
if( connectfd == -1 )
    bail("connect()");
printf("Connected\n");

while(1){
    printf("Please enter a message to send to the Server: \n");
    fgets(writeBuffer, 255, stdin);
    writefd = write(sockfd, writeBuffer, sizeof writeBuffer);
    if( writefd == -1 )
        bail("write(2)");

    printf("Waiting for a message from the server\n");
    readfd = read(sockfd, &readBuffer, sizeof readBuffer-1);
    if( readfd == -1 )
        bail("read(2)");
    readBuffer[readfd] = 0;
    printf("Message from the server: %s\n", readBuffer);
}

close(sockfd);
printf("Connection Closed\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) indent consistently.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.

Comment: indenting multiple statements after a 'if()' statement does not make several statements part of the 'if' code block.  only wrapping the statements in braces does that.

Comment: when compiling always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )   The posted code causes the compiler to raise lots of warning messages.  All those warnings need to be corrected.

Comment: in modern C language, the modifier `static` comes before the return type of a function.

Comment: for ease of understaning, for ease of documentation, for ease of debugging; follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers. (I.E. 255, 256).  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using an `enum` or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the 'bail()` would be much better written as a single call to `perror()` followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the `htons()` function prototype is: `uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);
`which means there is no `int` parameter`.   To feed it a proper parameter, suggest using: `uint16_t server_portno = 9100;` rather than the current char array.

Comment: the `write()` function returns a `ssize_t`, not a `int` and certainly not a file descriptor.  Suggest reading/understanding the man pages for the system functions that the code uses.  Similar considerations exist for the `read()` function.  Also suggest reading the man pages for `send()` and `recv()`

Comment: when calling the `read()` function, the posted code needs to use the returned value (when >= 0) to locate where to set the '\0' trailing byte rather than arbitrarily setting the last char in the `readBuffer`,  Other wise some number of trash (unitialized) bytes will be in the message when it is passed to `printf()`

Comment: the call to `fgets()`, second parameter, should be the actual length of the input buffer, not ` less than the actual length.

Comment: the call to `write()` should use the `strlen()` of the buffer to write, not necessarily the full length of the buffer.  Otherwise, the data passed through the socket will contain trash (uninitialized) bytes

Comment: when the function `main()` parameters are not being used, use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: the third parameter of function: `accept()` should be a `socklen_t *` not a 'int *`

Comment: strongly suggest the client and server `forever` loops have some method of exiting the loop, perhaps a message received that contains "quit\n"

Comment: when communicating over a socket, the `keepalive` option should be set, so the connection is not dropped after the first communication sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code, in server:

```
printf("Reading from Client...\n");
readfd = read(acceptfd, &readBuffer, sizeof readBuffer-1);
if( readfd == -1 )
    bail("read()");
```

readBuffer is an array, if passed to a function, it is already a pointer to its first element, so you cannot use &readBuffer, just use readBuffer, then after read, you need terminate the buffer, as strings in C are just null terminated char arrays:

```
printf("Reading from Client...\n");
readfd = read(acceptfd, readBuffer, sizeof readBuffer-1);
if( readfd == -1 )
    bail("read()");
readBuffer[readfd] = '\0';
```

fgets does not let you know how many chars it reads into the buffer, so you cannot just the entire buffer to the socket, write the string instead, use strlen to determine the size of the string you will need to write:

```
writefd = write(acceptfd, writeBuffer, strlen(writeBuffer));
```

In the client, the same issues with buffer:

```
writefd = write(sockfd, writeBuffer, strlen(writeBuffer));
...
readfd = read(sockfd, readBuffer, sizeof readBuffer-1);
readBuffer[readfd] = '\0';
```